# Changed default mail client, but Spotlight still opens Mail.App; how to change it?

Tags: mail.app, email, spotlight

Because of some other bugs with Mail.App's handling of certain email formats, I've installed Thunderbird to give that a try. I configured it to be the default (from the Mail.App preferences). That seems to work.

BUT if I search for an email via Spotlight (Thunderbird's search is...well, I'm using Spotlight), clicking on a found mail item from Spotlight still launches Mail.App.

I suspect it's a setting in a plist; how can I convince Spotlight to open Thunderbird instead of Mail.App?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to set any default app is with [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) - freeware - old but still works in Yosemite.

It installs as a Control Panel item called Default Apps; you can then set many defaults - simplest are the 'Internet' ones, first tab - dial in your preferred app from the drop menu.
e.g.

[image]